# How to configure SpringBoot ObjectMapper

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, yaml, objectmapper

I need to configure `ObjectMapper` in two places.  I have a jar which is a dependency of my other projects.  So I have something like this

```
@Primary
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    <customize stuff>
   
    return mapper;
}
```

In one of my other projects, I need to make some additional customizations on top of the ones above, but if I do the same thing, it creates a new `ObjectMapper` instead of making the changes to the one I want all my projects using.
How can I make changes to the one and only Spring `ObjectMapper`

**Update**

I was able to get this working better by implementing `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer`.  But I have another, probably related, issue that in that the child project also uses Yaml.  So I have a bean

```
@Bean("yamlMapper")
public YAMLMapper yamlObjectMapper() {
    return new YAMLMapper();
}
```

This works fine as long as I don't have the `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer`.  But if I do, it seems to want to use Yaml for both the input and output.  My input and output is still Json.  But it uses Yaml for some internal files.  But I get errors because it's trying to use Yaml to read the input to the service.  This only happens if I try to customize the `ObjectMapper` with `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer`